# How to build and submit iPhone app for distribution with Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

i have done iPhone app now i want to submit in app store i have faced some certificate error like `this Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate`some one guide me where i have to put developer certificate and distribution certificate in code signinghere i paste Xcode 4.2 code signing column.`

`[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link : http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html

It has all details on how to create distribution profile.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create distribution certificate and distributon provisioning profile. After that, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5464634/902424